# HTML, CSS, Text Direction

Tags: html, css

I had a problem with css direction, Now after i fixed it i am trying to understand why the fix is working, So this was the problem:

I got on my css `html{direction:rtl;}`, I wanted to present numbers from ltr, So i decide using span tag and style this span tag with css `span{direction:ltr;}`, But i don't know why it didn't work i even tried `span{text-align:left;}`, Used `!important` on Both, **direction and text-align**, Finally i found 2 solutions:

1. The first is using the attribute dir='ltr'
2. The second is span{direction: ltr;display:inline-block}

I am using the second solution, But if anyone can explain both i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Which browser are you testing on? Can you post a fiddle or your code that shows this behavior?

Comment: Yes, some browsers do not support this. I think you are using IE or firefox

Comment: Looks like [all major browsers support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) I would venture to guess that the issue is that some only apply it on block level elements; hence, `display:inline-block` fixing it for you.  Per the spec, it _should_ apply to all elements.

Comment: according to w3c: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup...`Add dir="rtl" to the html tag any time the overall page direction is right-to-left.` and `... styling applied by CSS is not permanent. It may be turned off, be overridden, go unrecognised, or be changed/replaced in different contexts` so you should go with your first approach of using the dir attribute rather than css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into w3c specs I think I found an answer to your problem

From [w3c](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup):

> HTML or XHTML served as text/html
>
> Use markup only. The CSS2 recommendation recommends the use of markup for bidi text in HTML. In fact it goes as far as to say **that conforming HTML user agents may ignore CSS bidi properties**. This is because the HTML specification clearly defines the expected behaviour of user agents with respect to the bidi markup.

*Emphasis added*

So I am guessing that when you had `direction: rtl;` set in your css, it was completely ignored by the browser.

The spec clearly says that you should use the `dir` attribute in your markup for rtl layouts.

Although you have the CSS working for the browsers you have checked, it is **not a solution for all browsers.** Read the CSS spec for bidi/direction [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction)